Using the python protobuf library, how can I load a .desc (or proto) file dynamically and reflect the fields within
I've tried using a few different methods but all end up not working.
I'm trying to read from a directory and iterate all the .desc files and inspect all the fields in each class. I'm trying to build a dependency tree with the outer classes being the parent nodes and the leaves being the nested classes. I'm trying to do this all dynamically based on a root folder containing the .desc files (or proto files). Nothing is statically typed.
The error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 197: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 197: invalid start byte in field: google.protobuf.FileDescriptorProto.name
def gen1(desc_file, db=None):
if not db:
    db = symbol_database.Default()

with open(desc_file, 'rb') as fh:
    fds = _descriptor_pool.DescriptorPool().AddSerializedFile(fh.read()) # <- this errors
generated = {}

for prot in fds.file:
    fd = db.pool.Add(prot)
    for name in fd.message_types_by_name:
        mdesc = fd.message_types_by_name[name]
        Klass = reflection.MakeClass(mdesc)
        generated[(fd.package, name)] = db.RegisterMessage(Klass)

return generated


I don't know the protobuf library at all, so I can't start to tell you how to fix the issue, but that's a very strange error to get if you're loading a file in binary mode and passing it into a library. Are you sure your file is valid, and not reencoded in the wrong character set? The library seems to expect some parts to be UTF-8, but it is not, though I suppose it might be decoding the wrong parts in the wrong place due to some error I don't recognize.

The Protobuf hierarchy is confusing/complex.
The following is a basic approach to enumerating the contents of a Protobuf descriptor file:
from google.protobuf.descriptor_pb2  import FileDescriptorSet


with open("descriptor.pb", 'rb') as descriptor:
    data = descriptor.read()
    fds = FileDescriptorSet.FromString(data)

    # file: FileDescriptorProto
    for file in fds.file:
        print(f"{file.package}/{file.name}")

        # service: ServiceDescriptorProto
        for service in file.service:
            print(service.name)

            # method: MethodDescriptorProto
            for method in service.method:
                print(method.name)
             
        # message: DescriptorProto
        for message_type in file.message_type:
            print(message_type.name)
            # field: FieldDescriptorProto
            for field in message_type.field:
                print(field.name)


What version of the protobuf library are you using? I'm getting "Cannot find reference 'FileDescriptorSet' in 'descriptor_pb2.py'"
Is that .pb the same as a .desc file?

The latest 5.27.3

Descriptor file are themselves protobuf files defined by descriptor.proto and represented in Python by descriptor_pb2.py``

Turns out I rant it despite that error and it ran fine. Sweet! I passed it my .desc file that it worked.

I'm pleased to hear it!
